# SQL Server 2008 inconsistent results when converting datetime to varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table with two datetime columns and I'm trying to convert them to an iso string format using the following query:

```
select 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), date1, 126) as date1,   
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), date2, 126) as date2
from   
   some_table
```

But I'm getting two different results, one with milliseconds and one without

```
date1                        date2
2015-03-11T05:16:04.663      2015-03-11T05:15:43
```

I've looked at the create table script and they are both defined as datetime. I have no clue how the data is being inserted.

How can I get both columns to return with milliseconds ?

Comment: Does `date2`s value always have a value of 0 milliseconds? Because I think it skips the milliseconds if there's no non-zero digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server "helpfully" will trim the milliseconds portion if it's entirely 0. If you **need** the 0 milliseconds included (I can't imagine what you're doing where you need `.000` to be included) then you'll have to detect the trimming and re-add them:

```
;With Converted as (
    --Your existing query. For this example, I'm just using one date:
    select CONVERT(varchar(23),CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-01T05:15:43.000'),126) as date2
)
select
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(date2) = 19 THEN date2 + '.000'
        ELSE date2
    END as date2
from Converted
```

(And, again if for some bizarre reason you really need the end result to be a `varchar(23)` rather than a `varchar(27)` you'll have to add another `CONVERT` that wraps the `CASE` expression because the system's not smart enough to realise that any value that the `CASE` returns could always fit in a `varchar(23)`)

Comment: What the hell is the point of a format if it's not consistent. Thanks man it's not you fault mssql is impossible. I'll accept in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It is becouse the second date has 0 ms.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test ( date1 datetime, date2 datetime)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('2015-03-11 05:16:04.663','2015-03-11 05:15:43' )

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('2015-03-11 05:16:04','2015-03-11 05:15:43.55' )


select 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), date1, 126) as date1,   
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), date2, 126) as date2
from   
   #Test
```

Check this example.